# Installing Ubuntu on a microSD card

Tags: ubuntu, micro-sd-card

I have a 128GB SSD with Windows 10 installed on it and most of the disk space on that SSD I'm already using (for programs and stuff). The thing is, I also need a Linux environment because I'm a student and at classes and exams we use Linux.

Dual-booting is not an option because of the limited SSD space, so I had an idea of installing it on a 128GB microSD card. I've googled this and found that it is indeed possible but my question is: how smart is it? If I were to install Ubuntu on an SD-card, how fast would it run? Keep in mind that I'm not planning on using it for anything graphically demanding - it's mostly just coding and internet. By the way, my laptop has a microSD slot so I'm not using a USB converter (which, according to some articles online, can slow stuff down).

PS: I don't want Virtual Machines - no good reason other then I simply don't like them.

PSS: Also, if Ubuntu is too big/demanding to be installed on an SD card, I'm open to suggestions of other distros that may be more lightweight/

So, any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: The site looks hella dated, but have a look on https://distrowatch.com/ as there will be some recommended for USB drives. DSL might be a good one; https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=damnsmall

Comment: 128GB is little but not that limited. There are computers sold with Windows 10 in a 64GB or even a meager 32GB one. Installing an OS in a microSD card is a very bad idea. So, dual-boot is an option and I think you should think more seriously about what to do and perhaps prioritize having the tools you need over Windows games, if you're on a budget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have no speed problem with an SD card. Even graphics would be no problem, because the SD is only needed to load data, not while running programs. The Raspberry PI has an SD card as the primary storage medium.

You may experience longer load times than you would from the SSD, but it you don't do anything data intensive, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, assuming your hardware supports it.  Check your laptop's BIOS to see if booting from a SD is an option.  Not all laptops have this as a feature.  If not, you could boot from a USB to SD adapter.  However, that would limit you to the the speed of the USB controller and USB adapter.

Secondly, while it is possible, it wont work particularly well.  SD cards do not have cache or onboard logic that SSDs do.  They will perform visibly worse than a SSD.  In addition to that, the constant writing to the flash memory will wear it out significantly faster than a SSD with wear leveling.

Why not just upgrade your SSD to a larger capacity?  That option would make the most sense.

Depending on your laptop's design, you can simply carry another hard drive with you and switch drives when needed.  I have a laptop at home where the drive bay is accessible from the side.  I removed the drive cover and swap drives in and out as necessary.